WARNING: location-reference "x" did match multiple location-classes! (taking first one) - What is meant?
In a bigger project with multiple indexes, pagenotes and sectionwise bibliography I got that WARNING in the title of this question. Since I have a problem with the index in the epub (via tex4ebook) I ask myself if this Warning has to do with the problem in the indexes.
The problem in the index is within the epub, that most but not all index commands are linked and show only 3 digit or 4 digit numbers without being a link, beside the other regular links to a certain index entry term.
I think that the epub is not yet for publishing and I like to have it clean of incosistencies. Are there any hints for this? (No, with this I can not present a MWE).
Thanks for suggestions.

Have you translated that error message into English?  Because the usual message like that is "label 'x' multiply defined", meaning that you have \label{x} in multiple places.  And yes, you can create a MWE by removing everything not related and getting this down to 20-30 lines of code.

No, I did not have translated into english, this WARNING shows on messages during the run of pdflatex. - This has to do with label? I will make checks for this possibility.

Please copy the error message from the log file and paste it into your question.

I don't have error messages in pdflatex run, only some Warnings.

Copy the warning from the log file and paste into your question. Help preparing a minimal working example to assist people helping you: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228.
